# RegEx in Ruby for Converting CSV to TSV

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, csv

In Ruby, what's a regular expression that identifies commas within quotes (e.g., "dog, cat, foo, bar")?  My purpose is converting a CSV file to TSV, and some of my fields contain strings with commas within quotes that I want to preserve.

Comment: CSV files can play real havoc with a regex because of the potential for embedded commas inside fields. As @Doon suggested you're better off relying on a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be a regex?  Can just Parse the CSV using your fav csv library, and then rejoin using tabs?

```
require 'csv'

 test = '"foo,bar,baz",one,two,three'
 CSV.parse_line(test).join("\t")

  "foo,bar,baz\tone\ttwo\tthree"
```

Comment: Thank ya, Doon!  I ended up using FasterCSV::parse_line which worked as expected.

Comment: Converting a file (that doesn't contain tabs): `CSV.read("temp.csv").map { |row| row.join("\t") }.join("\n")`.